# Клиент-серверное приложение (чат) с использованием БД. java

Tags: java, sql

Разобрал как коннектиться к бд, изучил язык sql, разобрал JDBC, научился делать клиент-серверный чат, однако как прикрутить к этому бд не очень понял.

Есть ли хорошие гайды для языка java?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой пример на postgresql:

```
 public class TestDao {
    
    private final DataSource ds;
    
      List<Object> list = new ArrayList();

        public TestDao() {
            ComboPooledDataSource pool = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            try {
                pool.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
            } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка в название драйвера!",e);
            }
            pool.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:'порт'/'наименование базы'");
            pool.setUser("postgres");
            pool.setPassword("postgres");
            this.ds = pool;
        }
    }
```

Это с использованием зависимости с3р0 (пул коннектов). Дальше создаете connection, statement:

```
try(Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement('ваш запрос'))
```

Затем получаете результат:

```
try(ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery()) {
              while (set.next) {
                  list.add(set.getString('наименование колонки'));
                  }
              
            }
```

Имплементим AutoCloseable, и реализуем метод close():

```
@Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        DataSources.destroy(this.ds);
    }
```